# How to overcome the `connect failed` exception with mongodb?

Tags: software-installation, database, mongodb

I have installed mongodb once both trough the package manager (and purged it) and once following the [official install instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

When running `mongo` I get the error

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.11
connecting to: test
Fri Aug 22 22:07:28.792 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

When I run `sudo service mongodb start` it outputs `mongodb start/running, process 4378`, but when I then immediately run `sudo service mongodb status`, I get `mongodb stop/waiting`.

I have already tried:

- to `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock`
- `mongod --repair`
- I have checked the permissions:

  ```
  ls -al /var/log/mongodb/
  total 48
  drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb mongodb  4096 Aug 22 21:27 .
  drwxrwxr-x 23 root    syslog   4096 Aug 22 22:07 ..
  -rw-r--r--  1 mongodb mongodb 36676 Aug 22 22:07 mongodb.log

  ls -al /var/lib/mongodb/
  total 12
  drwxr-xr-x  3 mongodb mongodb 4096 Aug 22 22:05 .
  drwxr-xr-x 98 root    root    4096 Aug 22 21:27 ..
  drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb mongodb 4096 Aug 22 21:27 journal
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 mongodb nogroup    0 Aug 22 22:07 mongod.lock
  ```

All this was to no avail. Any suggestions? Other things I can check? I am running 14.04.

Comment: what does mongodb.log say? It basically sounds like the service is starting, hitting an error and then shutting down - the log will contain why that is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I had several problems. The first being that there was insufficient place for the journal files. The second being that I had installed something between the official repo and the official mongodb repo. It is fixed now.